# Can I resize these two images properly to the screen?

Tags: html, css, image

Technologies:

- CSS
- React
- JPG/PNG

Goal: 
I want to resize two images to look like this:
[image]

I am making a 'skirt customizer' for my mom/portfolio, where a shopper can change the 'belt' or 'fabric' with the buttons. The buttons work and thus, customization! However it looks like this:
[image]

This look is not ideal... I have tried adding classes (and ids) to the **image** and **container** tags and playing with the CSS. I have tried using max-height as "px" and/or 10% for the belt, 40% for the fabric. I have tried messing around with the height, width, max width with hopes on getting lucky with the perfect combination. I am pumped that the javascript works. I am hoping that someone with CSS skills can help me with the CSS. After this works, I hope to throw a 'transparent-skirt-frame' over the skirt and belt to give the skirt more of a skirt look but getting the sizing sized is really sizing me up. Please and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible options:

1. Put image into `div` with `overflow: hidden` and width/height according to your needs, set image `width` to `100%` and `height` to `auto`
2. Use `div` with background instead of `img` and add `background-size: cover` to div's styles

For first method, it will be smth like

```
//html
<div class="skirt">
  <div class="part belt"></div>
  <div class="part fabric"></div>
</div>

//css
.skirt {
  height: 500px;
}

.skirt .part {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.skirt .part img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.skirt .belt {
  height: 10%;
}

.skirt .fabric {
  height: 90%;
}
```

As for "skirt look", you can try to add `clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 80% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);` to `.skirt` ([clip-path generator](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/))

Comment: I can validate that all of the above code works wonderfully. This may have saved me days and I am extremely grateful to Stackoverflow, https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/, and Gennady Dogaev for the combined frontend results.